# Other sentence for "smoothening the process"

Tags: expressions, idioms, synonyms

In the context of -

> These findings helped us foresee various problems and hence smoothened
>   the whole process

what could be a more professional way of saying "smoothened the process"?

Comment: Please add new tags if you find the already existing ones inappropriate

Comment: The more common, and more formal, verb meaning *"made smooth"* is *smoothed*, not *smoothened*.

Comment: It just a suggestion. I'm not obsessing over a direct replacement for smoothened, since the complete context is unclear. From a value messaging perspective, shortening the process might be a desirable outcome of anticipating various problems, and shorter is a more tangible, quantifiable benefit than streamlined or facilitated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about **facilitated**?

> "These findings helped us foresee various problems and **facilitated**
>   the entire process."

This is common *professional* lingo.

From Merriam-Webster:

> **facilitiated**: to make (something) easier : to help cause (something) : to help (something) run more smoothly and effectively

Comment: Ah thanks, don't know why i couldn't think of that :)

Comment: Also "alleviate" or "ease" the process.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

These findings helped us foresee various problems, enabling us to streamline the whole process

OR

These findings helped us foresee various problems, and streamline the whole process

OR

These findings helped us foresee various problems, and shorten the whole process

Comment: Why have you suggested shorten?